# Why does microsoft contribute to the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, development

**Why does microsoft contribute to the Linux kernel?**
[[L. Latif, theinquirer, 2012 "Microsoft contributed more code than Canonical to Linux since 2.6.32"]](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2166123/microsoft-contributed-code-canonical-linux-2632)

Are the contributions focussed on code that will improve the compatibility with microsoft products (CIFS, NTFS...)?

Is the aim to show presence in public or learn how others solve problems? 
Has there been a public announcement on this topic, or is there an easy structure behind the commits?

Comment: You have to ask microsoft.

Comment: @jimmij "Ask them" is as helpful as rtfm and one can imagine that it will be quite difficult to find the right contact person.

Comment: No one on this site can answer the question about someone (the company in this case) intentions. You have to ask @BillGates or whoever was in charge and made that decision.

Comment: Samba is not part of the kernel (not part of Linux).

Comment: Microsoft is a very big place, it may benefit one division to contribute. e.g. azure use Gnu/Linux as one of there Operating Systems. (as you see from @golilocks answer, a lot of it is hyperv, this is the sort of stuff that would affect azure virtual machines).

Comment: A better question might be - why shouldn't they? MS, like most large corporations, is not a monolithic outfit. In the absence of a company-wide ban on dealing with free software - something that would be impossible to enforce anyway, the individual parts of the organization do what they think best to serve their interests and promote their products. As a quote in your link says: "Microsoft however is very keen to make Linux distributions work well with its Hyper-V hypervisor".

Comment: The downvotes here are excessive -- this is not an unreasonable question. I've edited that last italicized line out, it was kind of antagonistic/pre-emptively defensive and might set people off ;| You're free to put it back, of course.

Comment: @richard thank you. SAMBA is removed from the list now.

Comment: CIFS is the new smb (samba).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably they do it for technical reasons like everyone else.

Here's the output of `grep -R Microsoft . | grep -i "(c)"` run in the 3.13.3 source tree:

```
./tools/hv/hv_vss_daemon.c: * Copyright (C) 2013, Microsoft, Inc.
./drivers/net/hyperv/hyperv_net.h: * Copyright (c) 2011, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/net/hyperv/rndis_filter.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/net/hyperv/netvsc.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/net/hyperv/netvsc_drv.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/scsi/storvsc_drv.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hid/hid-hyperv.c: *  Copyright (c) 2010, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/video/hyperv_fb.c: * Copyright (c) 2012, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/input/serio/hyperv-keyboard.c: *  Copyright (c) 2013, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hv/hv_snapshot.c: * Copyright (C) 2013, Microsoft, Inc.
./drivers/hv/channel_mgmt.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hv/vmbus_drv.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hv/hv_util.c: * Copyright (c) 2010, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hv/hv_balloon.c: * Copyright (c) 2012, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hv/ring_buffer.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hv/hv.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hv/channel.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hv/connection.c: * Copyright (c) 2009, Microsoft Corporation.
./drivers/hv/hyperv_vmbus.h: * Copyright (c) 2011, Microsoft Corporation.
./Documentation/usb/linux-cdc-acm.inf:;     Copyright (c) 2000 Microsoft Corporation
./Documentation/usb/linux.inf:;    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
./include/linux/hyperv.h: * Copyright (c) 2011, Microsoft Corporation.
```

Most of these have to do with hypervisor support, such as virtual network interfaces.  I.e., as per the article you linked, they help facilitate linux guests running under Microsoft's [Hyper-V hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V).

Some of it *might* also be for the other way around -- running Windows guests on linux hosts -- which is also possible with at least [Xen](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Beginners_Guide#Creating_a_Windows_HVM_.28Hardware_Virtualized.29_Guest).